# Add value entered in cell to another cell in the same column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add the value entered in a cell in a certain row to another cell in that same column
Example:
If I enter a value in cell B12, add that value to the value in B17.
If I enter a value in cell D12, add that value to the value in D17 and so on.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Row = 12 Then
        Range(Target.Column & 17).Value = Range(Target.Column & 17).Value + Target.Value
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Problem is, that Target.Column is a integer and not a Character. So the Code will not run, since Range expects a char as column and not an integer (at least that is what I think the debugger wants to tell me).

Greetings,
Maverick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presumption that Column must be a letter is mistaken. To the contrary, Column is a number which, for users' convenience (not Excel's) is displayed as a letter in some usages. Therefore this code will work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target
        If .Row = 12 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Cells(17, .Column).Value = .Value
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

A rule you might go by is to address individual cells using the syntax for addressing cells, which is *Cells([Row], [Column])* and use range names only when addressing ranges comprising more than one cell. For this rule you need to understand that ...

1. When addressing cells, you can use their number or designation. `Cells(3, 2)` may also be written as `Cells(3, "B")` but the letter is more complicated and can't be used in calculations.
2. All ranges have names. But in the absence of a given name VBA will concatenate a name from its first and last cells, like `Range("A1:D4")`. You can further complicate this concatenation by interjecting other numbers into the name creation (such as you tried).
3. VBA defines a range by its first and last cells. Therefore VBA's preferred way to address *Range("A1:D4")* is `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 4))`. That looks effusive but if you are in a position where you have to calculate any of the  coordinates you will find that it's the simplest method.

Comment: thank you very much for you detailed explanation. this indeed helps me a lot to understand it better and being able to do such things on my own now :)